# How to calculate the average length of time in a list

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to figure out how long, on average, the price stays within a certain range. Let say my values are:

```
[10, 7.7, 9.5, 15, 8.8, 9.3, 7.7, 16]
```

For example when the value is between 8 - 9.9, how long on average before it is >14 (not going backwards)?

9.5 passes 14 in 1 day. 8.8 in 3 days. 9.3 in 2 days. 7.7 in 1 day. So the average is (1 + 3 + 2 + 1 )/4 = 1.75 days.

I am trying to create a program that does that calculation for me, but I am having problems.

Code:

```
list = [10, 7.7, 9.5, 15, 8.8, 9.3, 7.7, 16] 

def new_function()
    for i in list:

    while 8 < x < 9.99 (store index position as initial y);

    when x becomes > 14 (take index position and subtract it from initial   y to find length) 

    repeat for next i where  8 < x < 9.9

average = sum(length)/len(length)
print(average)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data in the csv file (10 rows or so)? It will make it easier to understand your requirements and help to validate recommended solutions.

Comment: the numbers are very similar to the values I provided in the list. I just used those numbers to simplify  things. 2 columns: date and price.  thousands of rows of data. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter in a list for each entry once a starting entry is found, until you reach one `> 14`. At this point add the found values to the totals and reset the run. Also add one to each counter each time around the loop, as follows:

```
data = [10, 7.7, 9.5, 15, 8.8, 9.3, 7.7, 16]
run = []
total_days = 0
total_entries = 0

for value in data:
    if value > 14:
        total_days += sum(run)
        total_entries += len(run)
        run = []
    elif 8 < value < 9.99 or len(run):
        run.append(0)
    run = [value + 1 for value in run]

print total_days / float(total_entries)
```

Giving you:

```
1.75
```